# Standard deviation on a vector of a row of several columns in steps of 10

Tags: r, standards, standard-deviation

I want to calculate a standard deviation step by 10 in R; for example

I'm a beginenr using programmation.

Example: I have a vector of :

```
exemple <- seq (0,100,10)
```

If I do `sd (exemple)` : I have the value of standard deviation but for all values in exemple.

But, how can I do to calculate the standard deviation to this exemple selectionning 10 by 10 steps ?

Can someone help me please ?

for more illustrations : Here is the exemple :

0   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  etc..

But instead of calculating the standard deviation of all these values, I want to calculate it between 0 and 10, between 10 and 20, between 20 and 30 etc…

Comment: Do you mean seq(0, 100, 10)?

Comment: Yes sorry. I will edit it.  but I'll show you a little picture
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90  etc..

But instead of calculating the standard deviation of all these values, I want to calculate it between 0 and 10, between 10 and 20, between 20 and 30 etc… 
Do you understand ? Or did I explain it wrong?

Comment: The SD is going to be identical for each of these two elements in your example, but see the code below.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, for a large number of values, you want to calculate the SD of values within 10 intervals. 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 ... am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: exactly. this is what i want to do @Joe Erinjeri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
example <- seq(0, 100, 10)

for(i in 1:(length(example)-1)){
  print(sd(c(example[i], example[i+1])))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Brigadeiro. I try it now and I see

Comment: If this answers your question you can upvote it and select it as the official answer!